# Numpy: Assignment and evaluation of functions over arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am very new to python. I need to fill a numpy array with values. However I am lost trying to understand the following behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
bla    = np.array([1,2,3,4])
fTilde = np.full(4,1)

for i in range(4):
    fTilde[i] = bla[i]

print(fTilde)
```

I obtain the expected

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

If I do

```
import numpy as np
bla    = np.array([1,2,3,4])
bla2   = np.cos(bla)
fTilde = np.full(4,1)

print(bla2)

for i in range(4):
    fTilde[i] = bla2[i]

print(fTilde)
```

I obtain the surprising result:

```
[ 0.54030231 -0.41614684 -0.9899925  -0.65364362]
[0 0 0 0]
```

Finally with

```
import numpy as np
bla    = np.array([1,2,3,4])
bla2   = np.cos(bla)+1
fTilde = np.full(4,1)

print(bla2)

for i in range(4):
    fTilde[i] = bla2[i]

print(fTilde)
```

I get the even less expected

```
[1.54030231 0.58385316 0.0100075  0.34635638]
[1 0 0 0]
```

I have no idea of what is happening. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it.

```
import numpy as np
bla    = np.array([1,2,3,4])
bla2   = np.cos(bla)
fTilde = np.full(4,1, dtype=np.float32)

print(bla2)

for i in range(4):
    fTilde[i] = bla2[i]

print(fTilde)
```

The problem is that when you do `fTilde = np.full(4,1)` the data type that's created is int by default so when you fill it, it's rounded off. Just set the datatype to float and the issue goes away.

Alternatively, you can also just do `np.full(4, 1.0)` and this also solves the issue.